# Intersection of two linear fits in Python

Tags: python, numpy, intersection

I made some linear fits of a curve looking like this:

```
data = loadtxt("data.txt", comments="#", unpack=False)
T = data[:,0]
L = data[:,1]

fit = loadtxt("fit.dat", comments="#", unpack=False)

G = fit[:,0]
H = fit[:,1]

coef = np.polyfit(G,H,1)

p_no_offset = np.linalg.lstsq(L.reshape(-1,1), T)[0]

y_fit = np.dot(p_no_offset, L.reshape(-1,1).T)

x_low = 0.99*min(G)
x_high = 1.0*max(G)
x_e = np.linspace(x_low, x_high, 100)
```

How can I get an intersection of these two fits (y_fit and x_e)? And how do I get the exact coordinates from the intersection point?

Comment: To find the intercept: for each line, get the slope (*m*) and y-intercept (*b*), or other parameters that define the line, and follow a formula that you look up by doing the search "formula for intersection of two lines". (Then plot it all to make sure it's reasonable.) If there's a step here that doesn't work for you, please clarify.